# How to create a cosmic string?

Tags: cosmology, phase-transition, big-bang, cosmic-string, topological-defects

I know about cosmic strings. They are 1-D topological defects in space-time which may had been created during the symmetry breaking phase transition during the big bang. But my question is  : Are there any ways using which we can create cosmic strings? And if there are any ways then what are those ways?

Comment: These are entirely hypothetical at this point in time.  There is AFAIK no widely accepted evidence they actually exist.

Comment: Have you read about the energy in, say, 1 meter if cosmic string? Do we have that energy available?

Comment: I know that a cosmic string have extreme amount of energy, that is why we cannot create one right now. But I wanted know about a theoretical way of creating a cosmic string.